# Using a default value using entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I would like to set the default value of a BigInt to a sequence:

```
ALTER TABLE Test.MyTable
    ADD 
        DEFAULT N'AdvWorks_' + 
        CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR Test.CounterSeq AS NVARCHAR(20)) 
        FOR IDColumn;
GO
```

This works great in SQL Server.  But I am unsure how to do this using entity framework.

Entity framework allows default values, but they have to be static values defined at design time.  (So I don't think I can use those.)

The column is not nullable, so I don't know how I can pass up a value that will get the default on the column triggered.

Note: I am using Entity Framework in the classic "Database First" mode.  I don't have any code first or migrations going on.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is fairly easy.

I when to the column's properties and changed StoreGeneratedPattern to Computed and it worked great!